# How to decrypt an encapsulated Time Stamp?

Tags: encryption, certificate, timestamp

I have a file called signatures.xml which is part of an Adobe AIR file. Now I would like to decrypt the information stored in the XADES Encapsulated Time Stamp. How can I get any information out of the encrypted string? Which tools are to be used? And do I need the public key to decrypt it, and where do I get it? (As a hint I think that this certificate was used: https://blogs.oracle.com/mullan/java-applications-that-are-signed-and-timestamped-with-the-geotrust-timestamp-authority-are-no-longer-working)
And this is the code:

```
 <xades:QualifyingProperties>
<xades:UnsignedProperties > 
  <xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties>
    <xades:SignatureTimeStamp>
      <xades:HashDataInfo uri="#PackageSignatureValue">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        </Transforms>
        <xades:EncapsulatedTimeStamp>

    MIIIQgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIIMzCCCC8CAQMxCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIGvBgsqhkiG9w0BCRABBKCB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            </xades:EncapsulatedTimeStamp>      
          </xades:HashDataInfo>         
        </xades:SignatureTimeStamp>
      </xades:UnsignedSignatureProperties> 
    </xades:UnsignedProperties>
  </xades:QualifyingProperties>
</Object>
```

Comment: The information seems to be base64 encoded, just the result is still a bit messy when I decode it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XAdES is built around X.509 certificates and related formats, so the "encapsulated data" is likely to contain some sort of ASN.1 DER data, encoded in Base64. But it's **not necessarily encrypted** in any way – just a thick layering of binary formats.

*(Indeed the `MII…` prefix is a telltale sign of an ASN.1 SEQUENCE tag hiding inside Base64.)*

I don't have the XAdES format description at hand, but after running the tag value through a Base64 decoder and then an ASN.1 dumper ([this](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/dumpasn1.c) or [this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Asn1parse(1)) or [this](https://lapo.it/asn1js/)), I get:

```
$ base64 --decode <data.txt >data.raw
$ dumpasn1 data.raw
   0 2114: SEQUENCE {
   4    9:   OBJECT IDENTIFIER signedData (1 2 840 113549 1 7 2)
  15 2099:   [0] {
  19 2095:     SEQUENCE {
  23    1:       INTEGER 3
  26   11:       SET {
  28    9:         SEQUENCE {
...
```

Conveniently the file begins with its own "content type" (like MIME types but for X.500) and claims to be a **PKCS#7 (CMS) SignedData** structure, essentially the same as used for S/MIME. OpenSSL can successfully parse it as such:

```
$ openssl cms -in data.raw -inform DER -cmsout -print
CMS_ContentInfo: 
  contentType: pkcs7-signedData (1.2.840.113549.1.7.2)
  d.signedData: 
    version: 3
    digestAlgorithms:
        algorithm: sha1 (1.3.14.3.2.26)
        parameter: NULL
    encapContentInfo: 
      eContentType: id-smime-ct-TSTInfo (1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.1.4)
      eContent: 
        0000 - 30 81 99 02 01 01 06 02-29 02 30 21 30 09 06   0.......).0!0..
        000f - 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00-04 14 d1 24 6b 80 8b   .+.........$k..
        001e - ae 11 fe bb 52 d1 59 7f-8a 04 aa 40 b1 bf df   ....R.Y....@...
        002d - 02 04 12 82 6c b2 18 0f-32 30 31 33 30 39 33   ....l...2013093
        003c - 30 31 31 33 31 32 34 5a-30 03 02 01 3c a0 51   0113124Z0...<.Q
        004b - a4 4f 30 4d 31 0b 30 09-06 03 55 04 06 13 02   .O0M1.0...U....
        005a - 55 53 31 15 30 13 06 03-55 04 0a 13 0c 47 65   US1.0...U....Ge
        0069 - 6f 54 72 75 73 74 20 49-6e 63 31 27 30 25 06   oTrust Inc1'0%.
        0078 - 03 55 04 03 13 1e 47 65-6f 54 72 75 73 74 20   .U....GeoTrust 
        0087 - 54 69 6d 65 73 74 61 6d-70 69 6e 67 20 53 69   Timestamping Si
        0096 - 67 6e 65 72 20 31                              gner 1
    certificates:
      d.certificate: 
        cert_info: 
          version: 2
...
```

Here you can see the encapsulated signed data – which, again, is prefixed with a type identifier and claims to be a RFC 3161 "signed timestamp". Following it are the certificates which were used for signing the outer layer (not shown here for brevity).

If you need only the certificates, you can use:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -in data.raw -inform DER -print_certs > signer.pem
```

If you need the signed data, there are various ways to extract it. Of course you could directly copy & paste the required bytes into a new file. But the "proper" method would be to do full signature verification and everything:

```
$ wget -q https://www.thawte.com/roots/Thawte_Timestamping_CA.pem

$ openssl cms -in data.raw -inform DER \
              -verify -CAfile Thawte_Timestamping_CA.pem \
              -purpose any -attime $(date -d "1 year ago" +%s) \
              -out inner_data.raw -binary
```

The CA certificate is only for verification, but `openssl cms` does not have an option to skip the signature checks. `-purpose` is needed because the signing certificate wasn't a S/MIME certificate. `-attime` is needed because the certificate has already expired.

Finally we get this **RFC 3161 "TSTInfo"** signed timestamp data blob. Unfortunately it seems to be malformed, and OpenSSL's ASN.1 parser will not accept it.

```
$ openssl ts -reply -in inner_data.raw -text
:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1112:
:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:274:Type=TS_STATUS_INFO
:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:609:Field=status_info, Type=TS_RESP
```

But at least its raw contents can be dumped:

```
$ dumpasn1 inner_data.raw
  0 153: SEQUENCE {
  3   1:   INTEGER 1
  6   2:   OBJECT IDENTIFIER.
       :     Error: OBJECT IDENTIFIER has invalid length 2.
 10  33:   SEQUENCE {
 12   9:     SEQUENCE {
 14   5:       OBJECT IDENTIFIER sha1 (1 3 14 3 2 26)
 21   0:       NULL
       :       }
 23  20:     OCTET STRING D1 24 6B 80 8B AE 11 FE BB 52 D1 59 7F 8A 04 AA 40 B1 BF DF
       :     }
 45   4:   INTEGER 310537394
 51  15:   GeneralizedTime 30/09/2013 11:31:24 GMT
 68   3:   SEQUENCE {
 70   1:     INTEGER 60
       :     }
 73  81:   [0] {
 75  79:     [4] {
 77  77:       SEQUENCE {
 79  11:         SET {
 81   9:           SEQUENCE {
 83   3:             OBJECT IDENTIFIER countryName (2 5 4 6)
 88   2:             PrintableString 'US'
       :             }
       :           }
 92  21:         SET {
 94  19:           SEQUENCE {
 96   3:             OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationName (2 5 4 10)
101  12:             PrintableString 'GeoTrust Inc'
       :             }
       :           }
115  39:         SET {
117  37:           SEQUENCE {
119   3:             OBJECT IDENTIFIER commonName (2 5 4 3)
124  30:             PrintableString 'GeoTrust Timestamping Signer 1'
       :             }
       :           }
       :         }
       :       }
       :     }
       :   }
```

Alternatively:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -in inner_data.raw -inform DER -i
```

Comment: perfect solution!